# Why is my Keras custom loss function not working?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, loss-function

I wrote a squared loss function for categorisation of one hot encoded data

```
def squared_categorical_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.square(1.0 - K.sum(y_true * y_pred, axis=(1))))
```

which works when given numpy array examples, such as

```
y_true = np.asarray([[1,0,0],[0,1,0]])
y_pred = np.asarray([[0.5,0.2,0.3],[0.4,0.6,0]])
squared_categorical_loss(y_true, y_pred)
```

The example above returns a tensor with the value 0.205 which is the mean of (1-0.5)^2 and (1-0.6)^2, which is the desired result and what should be an optimisable loss function that generally correlates with accuracy but when I apply it to a TensorFlow model

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss=squared_categorical_loss,
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
```

the loss decreases to extremely small values while the training accuracy stays below 50% which shouldn't be possible as a loss below 0.125 couldn't be mathematically achieved without the accuracy being above 50% so what is wrong with my implementation?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work only if y_pred is normalized (sum equals to 1).

I think that you forgot to apply softmax in the last layer of your model.